# How to correctly declare DCB in JCL/assembler for QSAM put-locate

Tags: assembly, jcl

I'm trying to write a program that will write some data to a temporary dataset using the 370/assembler and QSAM. I get a soc01 when executing the put.

My DCB declaration in the assembler code looks like this:

```
TEMPFILE DCB   DDNAME=TEMP,                                            X
               DEVD=DA,                                                X
               DSORG=PS,                                               X
               MACRF=PL,GL,                                            X
               RECFM=FBA,                                              X
               LRECL=25,                                               X
               BLKSIZE=3000,                                           X
               EODAD=EOF3
```

In the JCL, the declaration looks like this:

```
//TEMP     DD DSN=&&TEMP,UNIT=PUB,DISP=(MOD,KEEP,DELETE),
//            DCB=(LRECL=25,BLKSIZE=3000)
```

And the put command looks like this:

```
         PUT    TEMPFILE                                                
         MVC    0(25,1),HIGHSALE
```

I suspect that the problem lies within my JCL declaration, but i'm not having any luck finding anything.

Comment: I changed the Macrf part of the dcb macro to macrf=(pl,gl), apparently that is how it's supposed to be written. I'm getting a soc04 error instead. So the macro is as follows.

    TEMPFILE DCB   DDNAME=TEMP,
                   DEVD=DA,
                   DSORG=PS,
                   MACRF=(PL,GL),
                   RECFM=FBA,
                   LRECL=25,
                   BLKSIZE=3000,
                   EODAD=EOF3

Comment: /sigh; I branched over the open instruction.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a [S0C4](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=codes-0cx), i.e., you're trying to access storage that doesn't belong to you.  Presuming that you've already determined (from the PSW or via some other means) that the abending instructing is in some of the code your [PUT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=descriptions-putwrite-next-record-qsam) macro expands out to, and that you have no messages in your assembly listing indicating "no active using for...", where does register 1 point to?  Since you're using locate mode, register 1 must point to your data.

Just as a side note, I don't normally see block size coded in a DCB macro in a program.  Most shops are using system determined block size and thus you never see it in either the program or the JCL.  It doesn't hurt anything if you're more comfortable coding it.